# Active Directory LDAPS is enabled via self signed certificate. But the PHP client fails to authenticate with the AD server

Tags: php, linux, active-directory, ldap, self-signed

I have configured an Active Directory with ldaps with a self signed certificate created via AD CS role. I configured that with the help of this article.I want to connect a php application on a linux machine to connect with the AD Directory via LDAPS

https://www.trustzone.com/microsoft-ad-ldap-2012/

So after that I verified the connection with ldp.exe tool on the Windows Server 2012 machine. It gives the verification that connection is established.
So I created users in AD, in order to get the authentication for one of my php applications on a linux machine. So when I try to communicate via LDAP it works. But when I tried to connect via LDAPS it fails. I gave the IP address and host name for the authentication from the client side.

As I said earlier I tried to connect with LDAP and succeeded. But it didin't fail but it too time forever to authenticate when I provided the hostname; but when I gave the IP it succeeded. But when it comes to LDAPS both scenarios failed. I created the certificate for hostname according to the above link. I also added the hostname on the client machine to the /etc/hosts file.

Is this due to the self signed certificate issue ??. I'm really new to Active Directory.

I expect to authenticate via LDAPS also as well as LDAP. But for LDAPS it doesn't get authenticated. What am I missing or misconfiguring.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's likely the certificate. For one, you must use the domain name that the certificate is assigned to - you can't connect using the IP.

But then the certificate has to be trusted by the client computer for the connection to work.

For testing, you could just tell it to not even check the certificate by putting this in your ldap.conf file (likely at `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf`):

```
TLS_REQCERT never
```

With that, it will still use the certificate for encryption, but it won't verify anything about the certificate.

But for anything other than testing, you should make sure the cert is properly trusted, since part of the certificate's job is to verify that you are talking to the correct server. There are some instruction here (you'll need to export the certificate to a file first): https://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/tip/5838.html

Comment: Find some specific infos for PHP at https://andreas.heigl.org/2020/01/31/handle-self-signed-certificates-with-phps-ldap-extension/